# max_col only selecting two columns when creating pie-chart using openpyxl

Tags: python, openpyxl, pie-chart

I am trying to create a pie-chart where data is in row and labels are in columns. I want to plot for data in row 2 and till column 4. But when I run, it only selects two columns. Below is the code:

```
from openpyxl import Workbook

from openpyxl.chart import (
    PieChart,
    ProjectedPieChart,
    Reference
)
from openpyxl.chart.series import DataPoint

data = [
    ['Pie', 'Sold','Added','New','extra'],
    ['Apple', 50,3,4,5],
    ['Cherry', 30,5,6,7],
    ['Pumpkin', 10,7,8,99],
    ['Chocolate', 40,10,29,23],
]

wb = Workbook()
ws = wb.active

for row in data:
    ws.append(row)

pie = PieChart()
labels = Reference(ws, min_row=1, min_col=2, max_col=4)
data = Reference(ws, min_col=2, min_row=2, max_col=4)
pie.add_data(data, titles_from_data=True)
pie.set_categories(labels)
pie.title = "Pies sold by category"
ws.add_chart(pie, "G20")


ws = wb.create_sheet(title="Projection")
wb.save("pie.xlsx")
```

This my result:
[image]

But I expect:
[image]

**My problem:I tried changing max_col to different number but it selects only 2**

Comment: you want to select column A to D as per excel point of view..rit..??

Comment: I want to create a pie-chart for row 2 (i.e. Apple) and data for pie-chart are taken from cell B2, C2, D2. If I understand it correctly, in the code the `min_col` and `max_col` decide the range of column selection. In my case, it is working fine for  `labels = Reference(ws, min_row=1, min_col=2, max_col=4)` whereas for `data = Reference(ws, min_col=2, min_row=2, max_col=4)` it is not.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After going through the source code I found the solution.  `pie.add_data` by default treat each column as data series. So, I need to add `from_rows` value in `pie.add_data` to select the row as the data series and had to update `min_col` in `data = Reference(ws, min_col=1, min_row=2, max_col=4)`. Following is the desired working code:

```
from openpyxl import Workbook

from openpyxl.chart import (
    PieChart,
    ProjectedPieChart,
    Reference
)
from openpyxl.chart.series import DataPoint

data = [
    ['Pie', 'Sold','Added','New','extra'],
    ['Apple', 50,3,4,5],
    ['Cherry', 30,5,6,7],
    ['Pumpkin', 10,7,8,99],
    ['Chocolate', 40,10,29,23],
]

wb = Workbook()
ws = wb.active

for row in data:
    ws.append(row)

pie = PieChart()
labels = Reference(ws, min_row=1, min_col=2, max_col=4)
data = Reference(ws, min_col=1, min_row=2, max_col=4)
#data = Reference(ws, range_string='Sheet!$B$2:$D$2')

pie.add_data(data, from_rows=2,titles_from_data=True)
pie.set_categories(labels)
pie.title = "Pies sold by category"
ws.add_chart(pie, "H2")


ws = wb.create_sheet(title="Projection")
wb.save("pie.xlsx")
```

Answer (score 0):

I have not used Openxlpy much but see if below lines can help to resolve loop related query..

```
import openpyxl
wb = openpyxl.load_workbook(r'yourfile.xlsx')
ws = wb['yoursheet']

for rowno, rowval in enumerate(ws.iter_rows( min_col=2, min_row=2,max_col=4)):
    for cell in rowval:
        label = ws.cell(row=cell.row, column=1).value
        print(label)
        data = ws.cell(row=cell.row, column=2).value
        print(data)
```

Comment: My problem is not related to the loop. I want to create a pie-chart in excel for which data is being picked by `data = Reference(ws, min_col=2, min_row=2, max_col=4)` and this line is not giving satisfactory result when data is called in `pie.add_data(data, titles_from_data=True)`. I tried your code but it is not working.